# Mysql auto backup stopped working

Tags: cron, mysql

I have a MySQL DB on a shared hosting server.
It's been sending me daily backups for years through email, with this cron task:

```
mysqldump -ce --user=***** --password=***** mydbname| gzip | uuencode dbbackup_e.gz | mail ****@gmail.com
```

For some reason my daily email does not contain the backup file anymore (I receive empty emails).

Could somebody point to me what's wrong?

Comment: If it stopped without any changes in that cron script the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps the size of the dump file has exceeded the max attachment size that either your server or your email service provider supports.